# Issue with running Python on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've just started using AWS today. I want to run my Python app on Elastic Beanstalk but when I just type print "Hello World" , it results in an error "Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation". Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS. I can't post the image due to my low reputation.

Comment: You might want to look at the logs from your instance and see why deployment failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not enough elements in your question to give a diagnostic.

I would suggest to connect to EB console and gather log file to search for a more detailed error message.

I also would suggest to follow the steps in the documentation to go through your very first "Hello World" project http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python.html